# How to Get a Json from api/metrics of sonarqube?

Tags: json, sonarqube

I tried to use the GET method of api/metrics to retrieve a JSON to use for my program, but the documentation lack to describe all the parameter to use in the requestUrl.

for example in for my program I find, using the Google Chrome console, that the requestUrl is this one:

> http://localhost:9000/api/resources?resource=my%3AjavaSample%3AMandria%2Fsrc%2Fmandria%2FIllnessException.java&metrics=new_technical_debt%2Cblocker_violations%2Cburned_budget%2Cbusiness_value%2Cclasses%2Ccomment_lines%2Ccomment_lines_density%2Ccomplexity%2Cclass_complexity%2Cfile_complexity%2Cfunction_complexity%2Cbranch_coverage%2Cnew_it_branch_coverage%2Cnew_branch_coverage%2Cconfirmed_issues%2Ccoverage%2Cnew_it_coverage%2Cnew_coverage%2Ccritical_violations%2Cdirectories%2Cduplicated_blocks%2Cduplicated_files%2Cduplicated_lines%2Cduplicated_lines_density%2Cfalse_positive_issues%2Cpackage_tangles%2Cfiles%2Cfile_complexity_distribution%2Cfunctions%2Cfunction_complexity_distribution%2Cgenerated_lines%2Cgenerated_ncloc%2Cit_branch_coverage%2Cit_coverage%2Cit_line_coverage%2Cit_uncovered_conditions%2Cit_uncovered_lines%2Cinfo_violations%2Cviolations%2Cline_coverage%2Cnew_it_line_coverage%2Cnew_line_coverage%2Clines%2Cncloc%2Clines_to_cover%2Cnew_it_lines_to_cover%2Cnew_lines_to_cover%2Cmajor_violations%2Cminor_violations%2Cnew_blocker_violations%2Cnew_critical_violations%2Cnew_info_violations%2Cnew_major_violations%2Cnew_minor_violations%2Cnew_violations%2Copen_issues%2Coverall_branch_coverage%2Cnew_overall_branch_coverage%2Coverall_coverage%2Cnew_overall_coverage%2Coverall_line_coverage%2Cnew_overall_line_coverage%2Cnew_overall_lines_to_cover%2Coverall_uncovered_conditions%2Cnew_overall_uncovered_conditions%2Coverall_uncovered_lines%2Cnew_overall_uncovered_lines%2Cpackage_cycles%2Cpackage_feedback_edges%2Cpackage_tangle_index%2Cprojects%2Cpublic_api%2Cpublic_documented_api_density%2Cpublic_undocumented_api%2Calert_status%2Creopened_issues%2Csqale_rating%2Cskipped_tests%2Cstatements%2Cteam_size%2Csqale_index%2Csqale_debt_ratio%2Cuncovered_conditions%2Cnew_it_uncovered_conditions%2Cnew_uncovered_conditions%2Cuncovered_lines%2Cnew_it_uncovered_lines%2Cnew_uncovered_lines%2Ctests%2Ctest_execution_time%2Ctest_errors%2Ctest_failures%2Ctest_success_density

is it possible to find a more detailed documentation or the way I try to solve my problem is not the correct one?

Comment: I already visited the SonarSource API Documentation but is really vague to me. Someone knows where find a better documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Just add `&format=json` to the parameters.

See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE43/Web+Service+API#WebServiceAPI-ResponseFormats

Comment: ok I understand that, but is not clear to me how call it from an outside program. how to do it corretly?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question how to call from a outside comment:

If you want to call the SonarQube Web Service API from a Java program you can use the Apache HTTP Client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9000/api/resources?metrics=lines");

    try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);) {
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
    }
}
```

In this case it prints all projects on SonarQube and additionaly the metric "lines". You can add multiple metrics to the list, separated by a comma:

```
"http://localhost:9000/api/resources?metrics=lines,blocker_violations"
```