# How to use SonarQube web API?

Tags: java, sonarqube, apache-httpclient-4.x

Previously, I asked about [how to export custom data from SonarQube Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198487/export-custom-sonarqube-report/46212879#46212879), and the Sonar Team suggests me that I should use Web API.

After some research, I'm still struggling on how to use the Web API. (
I'm very unfamiliar with how the Web API works)

After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526187/how-to-get-a-json-from-api-metrics-of-sonarqube), I realise that I can use Java code to do that. (I've just gone through how to use Apache Http Client) However, after run

`HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9000/api/issues?metrics=lines");`(copied from that post)

I got:

`HTTP/1.1 404 
{"errors":[{"msg":"Unknown url : /api/issues"}]}`

After I change this line to:

`HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9000/project/issues?facetMode=effort&id=project%3Atesting&resolved=false&types=CODE_SMELL");`

I got:

`HTTP/1.1 200 
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" charset="UTF-8"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"><meta name="application-name" content="SonarQube"/><meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF"/><meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-512x512.png"/><link href="/css/sonar.bf342fee.css" rel="stylesheet"><title>SonarQube</title></head><body><div id="content"><div class="global-loading"><i class="spinner global-loading-spinner"></i> <span class="global-loading-text">Loading...</span></div></div><script>window.baseUrl=""</script><script src="/js/vendor.0ba4fd94.js"></script><script src="/js/app.bf342fee.js"></script></body></html>`

Which is not what I expect as well.

I'm wondering what's the right way to use the [Web API](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/)? For example, if I want to get the code smells for a project. How the code should be in Java?

Here is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9000/api/issues?metrics=lines");
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9000/project/issues?facetMode=effort&id=project%3Atesting&resolved=false&types=CODE_SMELL");

        try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);) {
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The SonarQube web API lives under the `/api` context path, as per the SonarQube documentation, along with the section and the operation (which you seem to be missing).

As an example, to search for issues on localhost running on port 9000, send a `GET` to `http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?pageSize=500&componentKeys=YOUR_COMPONENT` and parse the JSON response.

You may need to provide authorization as well, which is sent as either a BASIC username password combo, or an access token which you can retrieve via the web client.

Comment: Could you also explain what should I put after the '?' mark?
In your case, you put pageSize=500 and componentKeys=YOUR_COMPONENT. I've found that componentKeys is one of the parameters under 'issues/search'. What about pageSize? Where can I find this kind of parameters?

Comment: `pageSize` just controls the number of results you get back, 500 is the maximum. The deprecated docs list them, although I'd be surprised if they were removed: https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392181

Comment: Hi, Evan, will you be able to help me on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538316/sonarqube-how-to-login-with-the-web-api?noredirect=1#comment80041941_46538316)? Thank you!

Comment: Hey guys. When I run the url `http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?pageSize=500&componentKeys=YOUR_COMPONENT`, it gives proper search issues in the JSON format on the browser. But when I try to run it through the fetch API from Javascript, it doesn't seem to be responsing with ant results. Any idea why?

Comment: @AakashThakur Best bet is to post a new question with your Fetch API code and we'll look from there.

Comment: I have posted a new question and here's a link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577479/access-soanrqube-api-with-fetchapi-doesnt-return-any-result. Please do have a look if you get time.

Comment: /web-api/ path? (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/web-api/)

Comment: Any idea how the API_TOKEN is passed in the request?

Answer (score 7):

`http://localhost:9000/web_api/` can be helpful, explain the parameters, have examples of response and trace changes with the Sonarqube versions.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

It caused me some trouble that there is a copy function in the documentation, next to the method name. Clicking that copies a nun functioning URL into your clipboard, you need to remove `web_api/` from the copied URL.

This is the case for version 10.3.0.82913 and probably others.

Copied URL
`https://example.com:port/web_api/api/server/version`
Correct URL
`https://example.com:port/api/server/version`

[image: Example screenshot of documentation]