# SonarQube How to login with the Web API

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest, sonarqube, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm writing a web application that can display code smell result from the Sonarqube, but I also want it can create custom rules sometimes. Currently, I'm able to get the data from the server using HTTPClient in Java or XMLHttpRequest in Js. However, I'm really stuck on POST message to the server.

**In Js**, I've tried these code to log in: (the CORS has been disabled in my chrome)

```
request.open("POST", "http://localhost:9000/api/authentication/login?login=admin&password=admin", true);
request.send();
```

The response status code is `200` which is successful. However, when I try to perform some action that needs permission

```
request.open("POST", "http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/copy?fromKey=" + fromKey + "&toName=" + name, true);
request.send();
```

The result is `401`, unauthorized.

After some research, I've changed my code to

```
var base64encodedData = ("admin:admin").toString('base64');
request.open("POST", "http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/copy?fromKey=" + fromKey + "&toName=" + name, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64encodedData);
request.send();
```

The response is `405`, no method found.

After further research, someone mentioned the `request.withCredentials` should set to `true`. I added in, then I got CORS problem again. (with the CORS disabled)

(I'm bit confused about the Sonarqube API. The reason I'm saying this is, in my opinion, the purpose of this API is to simplify the method to play with the Sonarqube server externally. However, since it does not allow CORS, does that mean I cannot use the API on my own web page?)

Since there is no luck in Js, I switched to Java.

**In Java**, I ran this: (I've done login as well)

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/copy?fromKey=AV7dToVK_BWPTtE1c9vU&toName=testtt");
try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);) {

        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
}
```

I got:

```
HTTP/1.1 401
```

Then I change my code follow this link about [Basic Authentication with the API](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication)

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials
     = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin");
provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
      .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
      .build();

HttpResponse response = client.execute(
      new HttpPost("http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/copy?fromKey=AV7dToVK_BWPTtE1c9vU&toName=testtt"));
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
System.out.println(statusCode);
```

Again, `401`

In summary, my question is: How can I use Java code or Js code (preferred) to POST messages to the SonarQube server with authorization?

Appriciate for any help!

**UPDATE**

I'm now trying with curl, here is what I run in terminal

```
curl -X POST -u deb3dd4152c571bcdb7b965e1d99b23a4e5c9505: http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/copy?fromKey=AV7dToVK_BWPTtE1c9vU&toName=test_file
```

And I got this response, which I don't know how

```
{"errors":[{"msg":"The 'toName' parameter is missing"}]}
```

**Second Update on CURL**

I ran:

```
curl -X POST -F "fromKey=AV7dToVK_BWPTtE1c9vU;toName=test_file" -v -u deb3dd4152c571bcdb7b965e1d99b23a4e5c9505: http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/copy
```

Result:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9000 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'deb3dd4152c571bcdb7b965e1d99b23a4e5c9505'
> POST /api/qualityprofiles/copy HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> Authorization: Basic ZGViM2RkNDE1MmM1NzFiY2RiN2I5NjVlMWQ5OWIyM2E0ZTVjOTUwNTo=
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 179
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------c22bb5dd76f44ac4
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 
< HTTP/1.1 400 
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 56
< Date: Wed, 04 Oct 2017 00:43:47 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
{"errors":[{"msg":"The 'toName' parameter is missing"}]}
```

Comment: Are you able to login with those credential on the Sonar portal?

Comment: @Rizwan yes, I'm using the default login info which is login:admin, pwd:admin

Comment: I'm even able to log in when I call `request.open("POST", "http://localhost:9000/api/authentication/login?login=admin&password=admin", true);`

Comment: can you track the network call happening when you invoke via java/js client Fiddler can give you details about the header and as well.

Comment: @Rizwan In response header, I got this:

    `Content-Length:0`
    `Date:Tue, 03 Oct 2017 12:31:27 GMT`
    `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff`
   `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN`
    `X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block`

Comment: I think the curl request is not correctly formed for the POST call with the field/form parameter, instead it is query parameter.. can you try to tweak and see what’s the result? Use -F ‘key=value’

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who got the same issue. I've got it working on Java code, Here is my code

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/copy?fromKey=AV7dToVK_BWPTtE1c9vU&toName=testtt");
post.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic ZGViM2RkNDE1MmM1NzFiY2RiN2I5NjVlMWQ5OWIyM2E0ZTVjOTUwNTo="); 
try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);) {

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
}
```

You may notice I've added a line which sets the header. I've done something similar before to encode my login and password to this base64 format, but  they all not working somehow. This working encoded string was taking from the CURL method. (from my second update)

I've tried some online base64 encoding and decoding tool, but the result doesn't match what I got from the CURL method, So if you are struggling on this, run CURL to get your encoded header and pass it in! If anyone could explain a better version, that would be great!

Also, I'm still interested in get the Js version working. If you know the answer, please share!

Comment: Thanks for this


```
I've tried some online base64 encoding and decoding tool, but the result doesn't match what I got from the CURL method, So if you are struggling on this, run CURL to get your encoded header and pass it in! If anyone could explain a better version, that would be great!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer in C#:

```
string url = "http://localhost:9000/api/project_badges/quality_gate?project=projectName";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
string responseString = string.Empty;
var response = client.PostAsync(url, null).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseContent = response.Content;
    responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```