# Access SonarQube API with FetchAPI doesn't return any result

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, fetch-api, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to access SonarQube API through Fetch but it doesn't seem to be responding with any results. It just resolves with an opaque token.

Let me share what I have done so far:

```
fetch("http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?pageSize=500&componentKeys=bactch_analysis_key",{
            mode:'no-cors'
        }) // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
            .then(
                res => res.json()
            )
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(err =>  {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

I am setting the `mode` as `no-cors` as it was throwing ACAO errors.

The same URL works perfect when openend from chrome or inspected through Postman.

This is what I get when the promise resolves:
[image]

Below is the error that I get from the `catch` clause:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at fetch.then.res (index.html:51)
```

Comment: You don't seem to be providing any authorization in your request? Have you tried adding an `Authorization` header? Chrome and Postman are probably re-using your existing session, which is why they're working.

Comment: It will follow this format : `headers:{ 'Authorization':'Bearer '+ bearer_token }`. But what will be the `bearer_token` in this case?

Comment: You can generate the `bearer_token` - see this reference: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle response - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input)

Comment: *“I am setting the `mode` as `no-cors` as it was throwing ACAO errors”*. That’s not going to fix things. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input/43319482#43319482 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors/43268098#43268098. You need to instead CORS-enable that `http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search` API endpoint.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I guess that can be done on the `.htaccess` file inside the sonarqube directory that I have AFAIK.

Comment: @EvanKnowles I tried with authorization but still got the opque token. I guess the problem is of setting mode as `no-cors` only as stated by side above.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I followed the method as shown in this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors/43268098. It returns `https://tranquil-inlet-49324.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?pageSize=500&componentKeys=bactch_analysis_28_1_key 404 (Not Found)`